# Type inference does not include dynamic Object.fromEntries() properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to dynamically generate my styles using material UI's `makeStyles()` but when I use `Object.fromEntries` in conjunction, the type is not correctly inferred.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const paperViewportSizes = {
  sm: '30',
  md: '50',
  lg: '66',
  xl: '80',
} 

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  App: {
    color: "hotpink"
  },
  ...Object.fromEntries(
    ['Sm', 'Md', 'Lg'].map((size, i) => [
      `contentPadding${size}`,
      { padding: theme.spacing((i + 1) * 2, (i + 1) * 2 + 1) },
    ]),
  ),
  ...Object.entries(paperViewportSizes).reduce(
    (acc, [key, size]) => ({
      ...acc,
      ...{
        [`paper_${key}_h`]: { height: `${size}vh` },
        [`paper_${key}_w`]: { width: `${size}vw` },
      },
    }),
    {
      paper_auto_h: { height: 'auto' },
      paper_auto_w: { width: 'auto' },
    }
  )
}));
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles(); // Record<"App" | "paper_auto_h" | "paper_auto_w", string>
  return (
    <>
    <div className={classes.App}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Is there anything that I am missing?](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-visvesvaraya-m8bvr?file=/src/App.tsx)

[image]

Comment: I am not getting that error in your sandbox!

Comment: @Iosif sorry I only had the `classes` initialised without using them (which ofc TS will not complain about), I updated the sandbox and the error is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Object.fromEntries` hardly infers anything at all. If you look its type declarations, you will see this:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    fromEntries<T = any>(entries: Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, T]>): { 
        [k: string]: T 
    };
    fromEntries(entries: Iterable<readonly any[]>): any;
}
```

You can see, that it either returns `any`, or `{ [k: string]: T }`. In the former case, there's no inference, in the latter - there are no limitations on the keys type. Consider this example:

```
const foo = Object.fromEntries<number>([
  // I'm writing "as const" because typescript expects to get
  // type "[string | number | symbol, number]", but if you don't
  // add "as const", it will consider ['a', 1] to be "(string | number)[]"
  ['a', 1] as const,
  ['b', 2] as const,
])
```

Here `foo` is of type `{ [k: string]: number }`, and **not** of type `{ [k in 'a' | 'b']: number }`, even though this type would be more precise. Now see what happens with spread operator:

```
const bar = {
   ...foo,
   c: 8
}
```

Here `bar` is of type `{ c: number }`. You can see typescript just ignored `foo`. I'm not an expert in the way spread operator inference works in TS, if you are interested, you can google that.

Any way this is what happens in your code and the only way to get correct types would be to cast the type manually

```
...(
  Object.fromEntries(/*...*/) as Record<
    'contentPaddingSm' | 'contentPaddingLg' | 'contentPaddingMd',
    { padding: string }
  >
)
```